# cancel mouse events

Tags: javascript, events

i'm using a mouse event for an outer element. how to **cance**l the from triggering by **sub elements** with reasonably small code

```
  <div onmouseout='myfunc()'>
     <div>item1</div>
     <div>item2</div>
     ...............
     <div>item n</div>
  </div>
```

mouseevent *should not apply to **item1 to n***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up myfunc to only recognize the element the mouse event was set on-

```
function myfunc(e){
  var who=window.event? event.srcElement || e.target;
  if(who.onmouseout==arguments.callee){
    // whatever
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `mouseout` event fires when you are leaving the parent element and entering child elements. In order to treat the all the child elements as a single block with the parent element, you case use the `mouseleave` event: in native JS it's for IE only, but there is a cross-browser implementation in [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com).

Comment: do you know the exact jquery page that handles the problem